# RequiredFieldValidator,... effect on others controls

Tags: asp.net

In one page of my ASP web application, i am using bootstrap tabs and in each tab there are controls and (RegularExpressionValidator, CompareValidator, RequiredFieldValidator, ..) but the problem is when i am filling-up the controls which are inside tab1 and click on insert button which is also into tab1 its not processing the order, as the Validator 's messages appears which are into tab2. I tried to wrap each tab contents with panel but it dosent work :-(

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function BtnClick() {
         //var v1 = "#<%= CompNmeTxtBox.ClientID %>";
     //var v2 = "#<%= UsrNme.ClientID %>";
     //var v3 = "#<%= UsrTypeDrDo.ClientID %>";
     //var v4 = "#<%= fnbox.ClientID %>";
     //var v5 = "#<%= lnamebox.ClientID %>";
     //var v6 = "#<%= BizCateDDL.ClientID %>";
     //var v7 = "#<%= SubCatBizDDL.ClientID %>";
     //var v8 = "#<%= passtxtbx1.ClientID %>";
     //var v10 = "#<%= emailbox.ClientID %>";

     var val = Page_ClientValidate();
     if (!val) {
         var i = 0;
         for (; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
             if (!Page_Validators[i].isvalid) {
                 $("#" + Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate)
                     .css("border-color", "red");
             }
         }
     }
     return val;
 }
</script>
```

Comment: You could use ValidationGroup's to separate the validation for each tab.

Comment: ConnorsFan solution is correct, validationGroup will get you what you are looking for.  Set ValidationGroup for controls/validators on tab1 to "Tab1", and so on.

Comment: @ConnorsFan thank you can you make it as an answer ;-)

Comment: @Znar - You're welcome! I added the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to validate the data for each tab separately, you can set a different ValidationGroup for each one.