# How can I make the textbox control show red as well

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am using asp.net `RequiredFieldValidator` while it is failing and showing the correct fields what I want to do is change the active control to red i.e not display just a message so the user knows how which control and see it better

[image]

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="validationSummary"  runat="server" ValidationGroup="fhsMain" ForeColor="Red" HeaderText="Please ensure values are in the following fields" />

 <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">
                            First Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtFirstName" CssClass="form-control" Width="60%" Skin="Bootstrap" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ValidationGroup="fhsMain" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtFirstName" ErrorMessage="First Name"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I highlight a textbox border red when it is required?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237890/how-do-i-highlight-a-textbox-border-red-when-it-is-required)

Comment: There is no built in way to do this with the RequiredFieldValidator - easiest way would probably be use a CustomValidator and do it on the server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Text Box Color using Required Field Validator. No Extender Controls Please](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196859/change-text-box-color-using-required-field-validator-no-extender-controls-pleas)

Comment: You can check this post, where Znar did something similar for the border: [RequiredFieldValidator,… effect on others controls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36167884/requiredfieldvalidator-effect-on-others-controls/36181328#36181328).

Answer (score 1):

Based upon what you indicate as your goal I believe you should add the [Text attribute to your validator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ytkayke0(v=vs.110).aspx) (see the last line in the example below). This is separate from the [ErrorMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7ex4yy4(v=vs.110).aspx) which renders in your ValidationSummary. When the validator fails, the text will display where you put the validator and the errormessage will display in your summary.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ValidationGroup="fhsMain" 
runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtFirstName" ErrorMessage="First Name" 
Text="Text To Display"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

If you really want the input itself to change colors then you're going to need to implement some custom Javascript or utilize an external library like [formvalidation.io.](http://formvalidation.io/examples/requiring-at-least-one-field/)

Comment: Just a note: The answers on the linked questions provide excellent examples of possible Javascript you could use. This answer focuses on explaining how to not display "just a message".

Comment: Daniel that is not what i mean i was wanting to highlight the overall textbox at present.